# Tax is not included in Sagepay transaction

Tags: orders, magento2.2.6, tax-calculation, sagepay

While placing order from Admin using Sagepay, Tax is included in order total but Tax is not being included on sagepay transaction.  Even I've set "Include Tax In Order Total" to "Yes".
I am using Ebizmart Sagepay Suite.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: are you using Magentos default taxation logic?